# angularjs/cli- Ng is command is not working as globle

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have installed the angular/cli but ng command is not working as global

C:\Projects>ng -v
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please use the angular tag for angular 2+ questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps to start with angular CLI.

First update node version:

1. So, first check your node version by typing command `node -v`.
2. If node version is lower than 6.x.x then update it because angular CLI requires node version to be higher than 6.x.x. To update node version run the below command.

   `nvm install <new version> --reinstall-packages-from=<old version>`

   **`Ex: nvm install 7.10.0 --reinstall-packages-from=5.1.0`**

   Then run command: `nvm use 7.10.0`
3. After this run command `npm install -g @angular/cli` to install **Angular CLI**.
4. Then `ng new my-new-project` to create new project.
5. Then `cd my-new-project` to go inside created project directory.
6. And then finally `ng serve` to run your app.

**Extra:**
To update your angular 2 project into angular 4 project run below command:

```
    * On Linux/Mac: npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-    
                     server,router,animations}@next --save server,router,animations}@next --save

     * On Windows: npm install @angular/common@next @angular/compiler@next @angular/compiler-cli@next @angular/core@next 
                   @angular/forms@next @angular/http@next @angular/platform-browser@next @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next 
                   @angular/platform-server@next @angular/  router@next @angular/animations@next --save
```

Answer (score 0):

In your command line tool use: `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Make sure you have installed NodeJS first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was related to node version, i have upgraded the node version higher than 6.x.x and now it is working.