# ng help - 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: angular, angular-cli

ng command is not getting recognized when used. I have already tried installing angular at global level and did the settings as per

[Angular's - 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019694/angulars-ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable)

[angularjs/cli- Ng is command is not working as globle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168199/angularjs-cli-ng-is-command-is-not-working-as-globle)

but no luck.

Can you please let me know what specific settings are required to achieve this.

> Error: ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Adding project structure as needed

[image]

Comment: Did you installed angular cli like this: npm i -g @angular/cli ?

Comment: Are other global npm packages working ? For instance, install `nodemon` and run it, see if the error is the same

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have `nodeJS` installed. Best of all, the latest version. You can see if it's working by typing `node -v`. Your node version should be greater than `6.x.x`.
Then install angular cli globaly using `npm install -g @angular/cli`. Then create your project using `ng new yourprojectname` or try to start your existing cli project by using `ng serve` in the project root.

Comment: I already have latest version of node installed. also, installed angular cli globally but still this is not working.

Comment: can you update your question with the project structure ?

Comment: You mean with all files?

Comment: maybe a photo from your folder structure and paste the content of your  `packgage.json`

Comment: Have updated post with structure. package.json is tool long to paste.

Comment: Eventually I have solved this issue by adding ng path in the system environment variable. Thanks for all who responded to my question.

Answer (score 0):

-->First check angualr cli installed or not by using,
 ng -v, 
if not install angualr cli by using

npm install -g @angular/cli
.then

1. Go to the folder “C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm” and copy two files
   i. ng File
   ii. ng command script
2. Now navigate to your angular application folder let say (my angular application folder is D:\AngularApplication(where you can see the angular.json file)
3. Paste above two files
4. Now windows command prompt also supports ng commands.

Everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows at first try install(or reinstall) [npm](https://nodejs.org/en/) or [node](https://nodejs.org/en/). Then hit the following command.

```
**set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\[YOUR_WINDOWS_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm;**
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Node.js and angular as an administrator or give your user an administrator role.